# Import CSV and Convert datatype in Sequel Pro (using mysql)

Tags: mysql, sequelpro

I am importing csv data to Sequel pro. One of the columns is called fees and it contains numbers like 1713.192938. In csv the datatype is set to General. When I import it to Sequel Pro the datatype changed to VARCHAR. The numbers will show up in the interface correctly but when I try to do some aggregation like SUM(Fees), the results are so much bigger. For example, if I sum the top 10 rows of fees in excel it is about 1000, but when I did SUM(Fees)in Sequel Pro it showed 38,310. I tried to change the datatype to INT(11) too and the problem is the same. I also tried using functions like CAST(Fees AS FLOAT) and CAST(Fees AS DECIMAL (15,5)) and nothing worked. How could I convert the datatype both in excel and when importing to do accurate calculations?